# R 4.2 really messing up accented (latin) characters

Tags: r, character-encoding

Ever since I updated R from 4.1.3 to 4.2.1, I am getting problems that never showed up before. I have to work with Brazilian Portuguese texts all the time. I am using Windows 10.

First, my User directory is named `"C:/Users/FernandoSimãoeSilva/"`. Right off the bat, when I start a session, I get this warning message printed 4 times:

```r
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/FernandoSim�oeSilva/Documents": O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado (System could not find the specified path).
```

Whenever I load a library, I get something like this:

```r
> library(openxlsx)
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

Now, those 2 errors above are inconsequential because my codes run anyway. The library gets actually loaded. However, if I use `pdftotext` to read a pdf file, this is what I've been getting:

```r
> grep("Resultado", x, value=T)
[2] "Par<e2>metros            C<f3>digo da          Unidade                  Resultados       Faixa Aceit<e1>vel de                   ID da Corrida"          
[3] "Par\xe2metros            C\xf3digo da Amostra                  Unidade                 Resultados                             ID da Corrida Anal\xedtica"
```

As you can see, not only do the accented characters get weird, they also get an inconsistent representation (for example, `"â"` became `"<e2>"` and `"\xe2"`). The same issue happens when I read a csv file with `read.csv`, `read.csv2` or `fread`, whether or not I set `encoding = "UTF-8"`.

There are other issues, such as Rmarkdown not being able to render an HTML output that worked just fine in R 4.1.3. But I think the examples above are clear enough.

How can I solve this without having to go back to R 4.1.3?

Comment: FYI, I suggested an edit for your question, using code-fences (`\`\`\``) to mark off code blocks. While subjectively I think it looks better, it also resolves the issue with you needing to insert a space to get (e.g.) `<e2>` to display correctly. More info on formatting questions can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: (Curious, what is `sgrep`?)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. And sgrep is just a special version of grep that I created to find a pattern with any number of spaces between characters. So, it's the same as grep in this particular case.

Comment: It sounds as though you have strings in Latin1 (or some such) encoding, and R is trying to read them as UTF-8 (the default on Windows in R 4.2.1).  My guess would be that you have a `.Rprofile` file or similar that's not stored in UTF-8, and that is causing the issues.  Open it in some editor, and resave it in UTF-8 and the problems may go away.

Comment: For the `pdftotext` question, it looks the same:  `\xe2` is not a legal encoding in UTF-8.  Make sure your file is in UTF-8 before you read it, or declare what encoding it really is so R can convert it.

Comment: To clarify the pdftotext issue: my code runs pdftotext from the command line using the `system()` function, which creates a temporary .txt file. Then, it reads such file with readLines. The txt file is fine. I looked at it using Notepad. The problem is when R reads it. That's when characters get switched.

Comment: @user2554330, I tried that, but it looks like the .Rprofile files are already in UTF-8, which is my system default anyway. I opened them in notepad++ and tried to change encoding, but it was already UTF-8 (no BOM), whatever BOM is.

Comment: @KJ just ran chcp on the command prompt and I got 850. I guess this means that's not the problem either.

Comment: @KJ, I tried opening the Rprofile and Rprofile.site files as admin and saving them as UTF-8 (with BOM). Then, I couldn't open R or RStudio anymore and got the message "Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT". So, I saved them back as just UTF-8 and became able to open R again.

Comment: A discovery that may or may not serve as a clue: if I generate a txt or csv file with R and then read it, it works. The problem is with files generated outside R (such as with pdftotext or a csv generated in Excel):

`> writeLines("Acentos: á ã à é", "teste.txt")`

`> readLines("teste.txt")`

`[1] "Acentos: á ã à é"`

Comment: @KJ that's insightful. I did what you said. The file generated by `writeLines()` in R, when opened in Notepad++, is shown to be UTF-8 (without BOM). Then I wrote the same text ("Acentos: á ã à é") in Word, saved as pdf, ran pdftotext from within R with the `system()` function to generate a txt file, opened that file in Notepad++ and the encoding was ANSI. When I changed format to UTF-8 (without BOM) in Notepad++, it looked as messy as what R reads.

That's a diagnosis. Now, how can I configure R to read those files correctly like in previous versions such as 4.1.3?

Comment: One more note: I opened R 4.1.3 and ran the `system` function to generate another txt file. It was also ANSI. So, the issue here is making R 4.2 understand ANSI.

Comment: @KJ, That worked. I did `system('pdftotext -enc UTF-8 "teste.pdf" "teste.txt"')` and the txt file was read correctly, as long as I passed `encoding = "UTF-8"` to the `readLines` function.

So, great, this allows me to read pdf files, which is by far the major problem I have with this 4.2 version of R, and I'm really really thankful. Maybe I can live with the rest of the problems. However, wrongly reading csvs, not rendering Rmakdown because of file paths with "ã" and outputting annoying error messages are still issues. If R could work with ANSI the way it did before, it would be ideal.

Comment: Or maybe change my Windows settings to UTF-8 somehow, since it seems to be working in ANSI by default.

Comment: @Macacoveio I face [similar problems](https://fosstodon.org/@gd047/109380623151294024). Have you come up with a solution?